# Show $\ker(F) \cong A \cap B$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

Suppose $A, B$ are subspaces of $V$ . Define $T\colon A \times B → V $ by $F((x, y)) = x + y$.

I'm trying to show that $\ker(F) \cong A \cap B.$

I need to give an isomorphism. So I think I need show that it is linear, injective, and surjective.
To show it's linear, can I just say that it is linear since $F$ is linear, or do I need to somehow prove it further? Also for injective and surjective, I think I need to find an inverse of this? I'm pretty confused, can someone maybe show me how to start off? I been at this for 2hours, please show me how the proof works.

Comment: Type `$\cong$` to get $\cong$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks!

Comment: Just making sure, did you mean to write $x + y$?

Comment: @Rushy Yes, $F((x,y))=x+y $

Comment: By considering a typical element of the kernel you will discover $\mathrm{ker}(F) = \{ (x,-x) \in A \times B \, | \, x \in A \cap B \}$.

Comment: @joeb Could you please explain a little further how I need to work with this. I get that $x,∈A$ and $-x∈B$, so $(x,−x)∈A×B $, and that$ x∈A$ and $ x∈B$. This all follows from $x+y = 0$, so $x=-y$, so for $-x∈B$ and since B is vector space, by closure of multiplication, we have $ x∈B$ too. Is this all correct so far? I don't really get how to put this all into a proof

Comment: Are you asking me how I came to the equality $\mathrm{ker}(F) = \{(x,-x) \;\; | \;\; x \in A \cap B\}$ or how you should prove the equality? Also I cut some notation out of the description of the set in case it created confusion.

Comment: @joeb I understood the notation, but I don't get how I prove it and how proving it will prove $ker(F)≅A∩B$

Comment: Letting $K = \{(x,-x) \; | \; x \in A \cap B\}$, it is clear that $K \subset \mathrm{ker}(F)$, as $F(x,-x) = x + (-x) = 0$ for any $x \in A \cap B$. On the other hand, consider any $(x,y) \in \mathrm{ker}(F)$. Of course, $(x,y) \in A \times B$ so that $x \in A$ and $y \in B$. Moreover, since $A,B$ are subspaces and $x + y = F(x,y) = 0$ we also have that $x = -y \in B$ and $y = -x \in A$. In particular $x \in A \cap B$ and $(x,y) = (x,-x) \in K$

Answer (score 1):

I would start by proving $\mathrm{ker}(F) = \{(x,-x) \; | \; x \in A \cap B\}$. Once that is done, a good map to consider would be

$\varphi : A \cap B \to \mathrm{ker}(F) \; ; \; x \mapsto (x,-x).$

It has inverse $\psi : \mathrm{ker}(F) \to A \cap B \; ; \; (x,y) \mapsto x$, which you'll have to check. The fact that it has an inverse makes $\varphi$ a bijection. The fact that its inverse is a canonical projection (linear) makes $\varphi$ linear as well (recall that linear bijections have linear inverses and vice versa).

Comment: How do I check the inverse? Am I proving it's linear?

Comment: I suggested checking $\psi$ is the inverse of $\varphi$ in the basic sense that $\varphi \circ \psi = \mathrm{Id}_{\mathrm{ker}(F)}$ and $\psi \circ \varphi = \mathrm{Id}_{A \cap B}$. You can do this directly using the expressions for $\varphi$ and $\psi$.

Comment: As for linearity, I made use of a theorem concerning inverses and linearity (an inverse of a linear transformation is also linear). The fact that $\psi$ is linear is easy to see (check this directly or just use the fact that it is a canonical projection). I follows that the inverse of $\psi$ (which happens to be $\varphi$) is also linear. Of course, you don't have to invoke this theorem to prove linearity of $\varphi$ - you can do it directly if you want, but I thought it was neater to invoke the theorem.

Comment: How do I check that $ψ$ is linear? Is it a given because $F$ is linear?

Comment: Also is this the correct way to check the inverses:  $ ψ∘φ =  ψ(φ(x)) = ψ((x,-x)) = x = I_{A∩B}$

Comment: Yes that is correct, only I would write $(\psi \circ \varphi)(x) = \psi(\varphi(x)) = \psi(x,-x) = x = I_{A \cap B}(x)$. The only changes I made were to the very first term and the very last term. Also, when you go to check the reverse composition $(\varphi \circ \psi)(x,y) = I_{\mathrm{ker}(F)}(x,y)$ you'll need to use the fact that $(x,y) \in \mathrm{ker}(F)$ and $y=-x$.

Comment: You can check that $\psi$ is linear by seeing how it acts on linear combinations. So for instance, consider vectors $\mathbf{a} = (x,y),\mathbf{b}=(u,v) \in \mathrm{ker}(F)$ and scalars $\alpha,\beta$ and verify that $\psi(\alpha\mathbf{a}+\beta\mathbf{b}) = \alpha \psi(\mathbf{a})+\beta\psi(\mathbf{b})$. This would be directly checking $\psi$ is linear according to the definition of linearity. Myself, I would wave my hands a little and confirm $\psi$ is linear by pointing to the fact that it is a restriction of a canonical projection $A\times B \to A \, ;\, (x,y) \to x$.